# Multiple bulk URB receive data to particular URB in USB LINUX

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, usb-drive

I am developing small USB driver in linux kernel, my device has two bulk endpoints (IN and OUT).

I have two URB  (assume) urb A and urb B . I have submitted many receive request from URB A, after some time i am sending a command to device using usb_bulk_msg()  and submitting receive request from URB B.

The problem is i always receive all the reply from URB A.

**My question how to receive a reply from particular URB.**

**Is it possible to maintain many different URB for single ENdpoint in USB?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you submit multiple URBs for a single endpoint, they are put into a queue, and the first data transfer will be handled by the first submitted URB.

If you receive different kinds of data, all the URB's completion handlers must check the actual data.